# Java Selenium Webdriver chrome can't find element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on a on card inside a container. I have tried id, class,xpath but it doesn't find it. I unsure on what else to try to be able to get the element.

here is the code of the element I want to click on:

```
<div class="mtable" id="w-card" status="83" entertainer="1799">
    <div class="mtable-cell wc-gray-dark" id="widget-icon" style="border-color: ">
        <div class="caption"><img src="/images/default_entertainer_image.jpg" class="caption-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mtable-cell wc-white" id="widget-text">
        <div>
            <h6>
                <span id="status-83" class="label label-default ">
                    <span class="entertainer-name">Testing</span>
                    <br>Testing100
                    <br>Last Seen: never
                </span>
            </h6>
        </div>
        <div id="timers">
            <div id="lastChange" class="pull-left"></div>
            <div id="circle" class="pull-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

selenium code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"w-card\"]")).click();
```

I have run display tests on all of the child elements of the div as well webdriver is finding it but is saying it's not displayed?

Comment: Is there n error? What is it? Have you considered clicking on one of the child elements?

Comment: The error message I receive is org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: I ran isDisplayed and it returned that it found the element but says it's not being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Explicit Wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to wait for element to be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("w-card"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("w-card"))).click();
```

This will wait up to 20 seconds for the element to be visible before clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your Div is not visible. So do few things run a for loop with 3 sec interval for like 10 iterations and inside that check for isDisplayed() condition, does it ever gets displayed. Also if everything fails then try javascript click..thats never recommended but still saves us

Comment: I ran a isDisplayed test and it returned that it's finding the div but it's not being displayed.

Comment: ok..can u try clicking on one of the inner elements of the div that you are trying to locate..if nothing else works then the last option should be javascript which is sure to work..but never recommended

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an *iframe*, so switch to that frame.

```
        `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(by));`
```